# Docker - installing vcredist_x86.exe inside a running container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

i am new to docker. I would like to run vcredist_x86.exe to install msvcr120.dll inside the running container without using a docker file. I did copy the exe file from my host to container. My base image is windows server core.

When I am in the running in powershell , i tired using the command :
 & ‘C:\vcredist_x86.exe’
and
Start-Process -FilePath “vcredist_x86.exe”
but the installation didnt even start running. It just remained idle.

Output: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXPeR.png
Much help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You generally never install any software inside running containers: any work you do will be lost as soon as the container is deleted (and deleting containers is a fairly routine operation).  If some command doesn't work, you'll need to add more details to your question: what command(s) exactly did you run? What errors did they produce?  Can you provide a complete Dockerfile for your custom image?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. I did some edit to my original post. Basically, i am trying to install msvcr120.dll by vcredist_x86.exe in my running container. i tired using the command : & ‘C:\vcredist_x86.exe’ and Start-Process -FilePath “vcredist_x86.exe” but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, i managed to solve the issue using the start-process command.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a dockerfile how to install vcredist inside docker.

I tried different ways but no success. For example my dockerfile. It tries to install something but there are no libs and logs in the system

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
 
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]

WORKDIR c:/temp

ADD http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/6/056dcda9-d667-4e27-8001-8a0c6971d6b1/vcredist_x64.exe c:/temp/vcredist_x64.exe 

RUN Start-Process -filepath C:/temp/vcredist_x64.exe -ArgumentList "/install", "/passive", "/norestart", "'/log c:/temp/a.txt'" -PassThru | wait-process
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.

Comment: RUN Powershell.exe -Command \
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; \
Invoke-WebRequest https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe \
-OutFile 'c:\vc_redist.x86.exe' ; \
Start-Process c:\vc_redist.x86.exe -ArgumentList '/passive' \
-RedirectStandardOutput 'c:\Windows\System32' -Wait ; \
Remove-Item c:\vc_redist.x86.exe -Force

Comment: You can visit my GitHub [link](https://github.com/ngqiming) under dockerNatTutorial. I have the dockerfile there for your to download